# Inverse of $f(x)=3^x+2^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, exponentiation, inverse

I'm tring to find inverse of $f(x)=3^x+2^x$ but I don't have any clue. I  tried to $$y=2^x((3/2)^x+1)$$ 
$$\ln y=\ln2^x+\ln((3/2)^x+1)$$ 
$$\ln y= x \ln2+\ln((3/2)^x+1)$$ 
but I can't continue

Comment: Why are you trying to find the inverse? I doubt that it can be expressed in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

Comment: I don't think going from step 1 to step 2 is a valid operation

Comment: But where the LHS??

Comment: @Ovi It is/was missing a bracket. I edited it.

Comment: @MarkMcClure  one of my friend ask today  this question, I also tought it cant be expressed in closed form but anyway ı wonder may be it can

Comment: @Ovi It is a valid operation $lny= ln [2^{x}[(3/2)^x+1]]=ln2^x+ln[(3/2)^x+1]]$

Comment: Oh yes okay I see

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple closed form for the inverse.

Looking at a plot of the logarithm, $\ln(3^x+2^x)$, you get a very good approximation of $x\ln(2)$ in the negatives and $\ln(3)$ in the positives, as one term quickly dominates the other (their ratio drops below $1\%$ for $|x|>12$).

[image]

For small $x$, you can use the Taylor development to a limited degree

$$3^x+2^x\approx2+(\ln(3)+\ln(2))x+(\ln^2(3)+\ln^2(2))\frac{x^2}2+(\ln^3(3)+\ln^3(2))\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

and invert the polynomial (doable, but tedious, up to degree four; as it is just an approximation, one can wonder if it is worth the effort.)

[image]

Given the smoothness of the function, I guess that inverse cubic spline interpolation on $\ln(3^x+2^x)$ can do marvels.

Comment: how would one prove or arrive at the fact that there is no closed solution

Comment: I am lacking the tools for that. Anyway, the equation can be transformed to the pseudo-polynomial $t^\alpha+t-a=0$, with $\alpha=\ln(3)/\ln(2)$, which should be solved for $t$.

Comment: If you are lacking tools then you might, have some source which would confirm your statement about closed solution Or does transforming the given equation to a pseudo-polynomial confirms it (where I lag behind since I have never studied about psuedo-polynomials)

Comment: @Jasser: just intuition, such equations are nowhere solved. Had $\alpha$ been rational, you would have known that the roots of the polynomial cannot be expressed by elementary functions. But this is no proof.